# Ghidra and MSP430 decompiler does not show any functions

Tags: msp430, ghidra

I'm experimenting with Ghidra and decompiling code intended for the MSP430 FR4133 Launchpad.  I'm not sure if it's supported but Ghidra appeared to support MSP430 devices.

For a simple test,  I'm using the example code at this [link](https://software-dl.ti.com/msp430/msp430_public_sw/mcu/msp430/MSP-EXP430FR4133/latest/index_FDS.html) for the MSP EXP430FR4133 Launchpad.

This link contains a simple source program in this directory
MSP-EXP430FR4133_Software_Examples_windows\Firmware\Source\OutOfBox_MSP430FR4133.  It's a simple program with a stop watch and temperature sensor.

I decided to load the binary that's also there in the Binary folder.

[image]

Then I selected TI MSP430 16-bit and let Ghidra do the analysis.  The problem is that the decompiler doesn't provide any functions. I'm wondering if I've selected the wrong architecture or option?

[image]

**UPDATE 1**
I'm posting two extra images which show two functions but there's nothing of any significance.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Show the decompiled code at the position pointed to by the reset vector.

Comment: I'm not sure how to find the reset vector.  You'll see in my latest two screenshots there is a scroll bar on the right hand side of the listing box. Clicking on the two functions shows the decompiled code. These are saying "Could not recover jumptable".   I suspect this would occur if I've selected the wrong architecture.

Comment: The reset vector is at address FFFE.

Comment: There's no address at FFFE.  The listing goes from 0000 to 49db.   I'm wondering if I've used the right settings for importing with the format as raw binary?

Answer (score 0):

You are not decompiling a raw binary, but a text file.

If you look at the Readme, it indicates that this is a pre-built TI-TXT image.

Basically, it contains small chunks of data encoded in hexadecimal, prefixed with the load address. See the format definition [here](http://downloads.ti.com/docs/esd/SPRUI03/ti-txt-hex-format-ti-txt-option-stdz0795656.html).

Ghidra supports similar formats ([Intel HEX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_HEX) or [Motorola S-Records](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SREC_(file_format))), but not TI-TXT. I didn't find a tool to convert it to a supported format, but this could probably be done with a small script.

Comment: Can you clarify in my MSP430 example above which type of file is supported?

Comment: I'm not sure, I don't know the IDE. But apparently, TI maintains a [GCC](https://www.ti.com/tool/MSP430-GCC-OPENSOURCE) version for MSP430 so you might be able to compile the examples in ELF format ?